# Factory function is being called before factory loads necessary settings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, bluebird

I have a factory. I have the code below that will load settings and set variables right away:

AuthService.js:

```
  SettingService.loadSettings().then(function(config){
    console.log('loading settings')
    settings = config;
    expirationDate = moment(settings.trialEndDate);
    remainingDays = expirationDate.diff(moment(),'days');
    isExpired = remainingDays <= 0 ? true : false;
  });
```

Then in my app.js I have some UI-Router event-handler to check if either the trial or the license is valid:

app.js:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        AuthService.hasAccess().then(function(result){
            console.log('access result',result)
            if ( (hasAccess == false) && toState.name !== "settings") {
                event.preventDefault();
                toastr.warning('Your trial has expired');
                $state.go('settings');
            }else{
                console.log("License is valid or trial not expired.");
            }
        });
    });
```

AuthService.js > hasAccess():

```
  function hasAccess() {
    var d = $q.defer();
    // test if they have license
    console.log('Check if license present');
    if (_.isNull(settings.organization.license)){
      // No License
      // Return trial status
      d.resolve(isExpired);
    }else{
      // There IS a license
      // Validate license
      licenseCheck().then(function(licenseResult) {
        d.resolve(licenseResult);
      })
    }
    return d.promise
  }
```

---

**Problem: My function (`hasAccess()`) to check if my license is valid is running before the factory loads settings and expired status. `settings` is returning `undefined`. Is it possible to keep calling `hasAccess()` until `settings` is no longer undefined?**

Comment: `hasAccess()` doesn't return anything if the `else` condition is used. Since `licenseValidCheck()` returns  a promise .... you will need to probably return a promise from `hasAccess()` for both conditions

Comment: A simpler way to do this would likely be to use a `resolve` in the routing config

Comment: @charlietfl are you talking about how the `return result` is scoped to the then function? I suppose I can fix that by setting the value of `result` to a variable outside that scope. It's a good catch but I don't think it fixes the issue of my settings not being ready before `hasAccess` is called.

Comment: Also from what I could see, the resolve is set on state in my route provider, It didn't seem very DRY to add this check to every state when I could do a check with an event-handler on state change.

Comment: Yea you're right, I need to turn that entire`hasAccess` function into a promise. I updated OP.

Comment: You should **return** the `SettingService.loadSettings().then` promise and **chain** a `hasAccess()` promise from that.

Comment: So something like `SettingService.loadSettings().then(hasAccess())`